# Determinant computation is equivalent to matrix powering

Tags: complexity-theory, matrices

It has been claimed in this paper (page 2 last paragraph) that Matrix powering is equivalent to determinant computation.

https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/depth-four.pdf

Does anybody why is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

It states that matrix powering is **computationaly** equivalent to computation.
From another angle, Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm for matrix multiplication has complexity $\mathcal O(n^{2.373})$ and the same complexity is for determinant computation by fast multiplication.
The result comes from [Triangularization and inversion via fast multiplication](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-125/S0025-5718-1974-0331751-8/S0025-5718-1974-0331751-8.pdf) by *James R. Bunch and John E. Hopcroft*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the paper by Stephen Cook (numbered $[3]$ in the references of the paper you have mentioned). There, in proposition $5.2$ in page $13$, he shows the "computational equivalence" between matrix powering and determinant computation (and other problems).

Comment: Perhaps you should add the paper’s title, and if possible, a link.